# using values in describe blocks in a hierarchical manner

Tags: jestjs

I'm using jest for e2e testing, and I want to be able to use the value/response in one of the describe block in the next, even to create dynamic titles, say e.g.

```
describe('top most', async ()=>{
   let topVar = -1;

   describe('first nested', async ()=> {
       it ('get first response', async ()=> {
           const res = await request('/call');
           topVar = res.body.user_id;  // returns 1001
       }

   describe(`get values for user with user_id ${topVar}`, async () => {  // topVar prints -1
      it('get the values for the user with id ${topVar}', async ()=> { // topVar prints -1  
 
       
          const res = await request(`/user?user_id=${topVar}`);
          expect(res.body.user_id).toBe(1001);
     }
}
```

The value seems to be replaced inside the `it` block but, not in the titles. Is there any way to do that, also are the `it` and `describe` blocks always run in a sequential manner from top to bottom? I did find out about `--runInBand` but, am not sure if they meant test in different files or tests in the same file.

Comment: You can't. The test names are registered at test _discovery_ time, at which point `topVar` is still `-1`. And your tests should be _independent_, the order in which they run should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every describe should be independent, whe you need consecutive steps for a test then it's considered the same test and they should be part of the same describe, you can have multiple 'it' in the same describe, that way they should be consecutive.